# Modalviewcontroller problem

Tags: iphone, view, uiviewcontroller, modalviewcontroller

I am getting a `SIGABRT` error when I'm trying to show my modalviewcontroller.

This is the code:

```
    LoginPage *loginPage = nil;   
    loginPage = [[LoginPage alloc] initWithNibName:@"LoginPage" bundle:nil];
loginPage.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;
[self presentModalViewController:loginPage animated:YES];
[loginPage release];
```

I'm getting the error on the line: `[self presentModalViewController:loginPage animated:YES];`

Can anyone help?

**Code Update**`

[image]

**Error Message**

*Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key tableView.'*

Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide more of the error that the debugger throws? Have you enabled NSZombies?

Comment: @rckoenes: Please see new picture of error.

Comment: is there any more info in the debug console? Have you checked that all the iboutlets are set correctly.

Comment: @rckoenes: Please see above. I have connected the tableview in my login to the file's owner so all should be correct?

Comment: is tableView a property and did you synthesized it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why youre setting loginPage to nil. Try

```
LoginPage *loginPage = [[LoginPage alloc]initWithNibName:@"LoginPage" bundle:nil];
```

Comment: Hey, I tried but still get the same error. Please see above. Am I missing something? Thanks.

Comment: try taking out the initWithNibName and just put in init?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if the `loginPage` is `nil`?

Comment: put in an NSLog, have you tried removing the first line of the code?

Comment: @Jordan Brown: I'm not sure why it's throwing an error because I have another view calling another modalviewcontroller and that works perfectly... Do you know why? Thanks.